# Cannot pass options to modal into vue-materials

Tags: modal-dialog, vue.js

I'm having an issue with vue-materials. I've asked into github but the solution seems not to work. The issue is:

https://github.com/johnleider/vue-materials/issues/46

I've found the way (see my third comment, with attached images) but it doesn't seem to work. I attach here this comment:

A little bit more of light. Now, I changed modalParams as a function into computed:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
        'authToken',
    ]),
    modalParams() {
        const params = {
            opacity: 0.5,
            dismissible: true,
        };
        return params;
    },
},
```

Then, I can see this in dev Tools:

[image]

But my modal doesn't seem to apply this params.

[image]

Any clue?

Comment: Here you have a jsFiddle to check what i'm talking about:

https://jsfiddle.net/rayoplateado/z11fe07p/505/